# ASP.NET Dropdownlist selectedindexchanged event not firing on up / down arrow

Tags: asp.net, events, drop-down-menu

I have a server dropdownlist in an [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) updatepanel.  When I use the mouse to click on an item it fires the postback but when I click the up/down arrow to change entries, this is not firing. What could be reason?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" onKeyUp="this.blur();">
```

With **onKeyUp="this.blur();"** the control will lose focus when a key is unpressed, and that will trigger the onChange event.

Comment: however nice this solution may be, you are killing functionality, if you have a list with 10 items, and the user decides to navigate by keyboard, he exits the dropdownlist every time he clicks up or down.

is it possible to do  onKeyUp="this.blur();this.focus();"

?

Comment: although this didn't work out for me. But worth a try and need to take note :)

Answer (score 10):

Try setting the '**AutoPostBack**' property of the DropDownList control to '**true**'.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

See [ListControl.AutoPostBack Property on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more info

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether a postback to the server automatically occurs when the user changes the list selection.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to leave the control if you are using the keyboard in order to fire the event.

Comment: is there anyway to have this fired right on the up/down arrow?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to work with the arrow keys, you should use the client side event, `onKeyDown`.

Comment: can you give me an example of how this would work . . and how this can then postback to the server for actions